# Why android Messaging app is launched when I start an ACTION_SEND intent with */* mimeType type

Tags: android

I look at the android Messaging App source code, the manifest file said:

```
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
   </intent-filter>
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
   </intent-filter>
```

But why in my code, I start an Intent like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("*/*");
```

I see the Messaging app in the pop up dialog?

Comment: I'm surprised that more apps aren't launched by this Intent - it's basically specifying all possible MIME types. What are you trying to do with your intent? Are you trying to open a file using whatever apps have that MIME type filter? Why don't you find out the extension and set the mimeType based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because `*/*` is the wildcard that matches everything.

Let's flip it around. If Messaging would not match `*/*`, then *nothing* would match `*/*`, and it would be utterly pointless for you to specify it as a MIME type.